# how to formatting the default message for python logger

Tags: python, logging

I am using python logging module.

When I output the any message it has the default output string as prefix.

For example

```
    logging.info("any message")
```

gives output with prefix "INFO:"

```
    INFO:any message
```

I want to print simple messages without any prefix.

How one could do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

```
FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
d = {'clientip': '192.168.0.1', 'user': 'fbloggs'}
logger = logging.getLogger('tcpserver')
logger.warning('Protocol problem: %s', 'connection reset', extra=d)
```

Gives

```
2006-02-08 22:20:02,165 192.168.0.1 fbloggs  Protocol problem: connection reset
```

You will have to customise the FORMAT of the logger, similar to shown above.

Answer (score 2):

To output the message only, use the following format string:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s')
```